# Determine whether W is a subspace of V

Tags: vector-spaces

$V=\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$, $W=\{\mathit{f}:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}\mid\mathit{f}(x+1)=\mathit{f}(x)+1\space for\space all\space x\in\Bbb{R}\} $

I started off with determining whether the zero function is in W:

$0(x)=0\text{ but }0(x+1)\neq0(x)+1$

So I concluded W is not a subspace of V. But the answer said it is a subspace of V. Where did I go wrong? Thank you guys!

ps: Just noticed this is a duplicate question but I still need checkings on my work above, thank you guys!

Comment: Yep, you are right. The zero function $0$ is not in $W$, hence $W$ couldn't be a subspace. Could you give the reference from where you found this? I would think there was a typo and actually they meant to put $f(x+1)=f(x)$ (i.e. the space of 1-periodic functions.)

Comment: Alright, thank you! It's from a 2015 examination paper.